# Sending an email using Mailchimp for Shopify

Tags: shopify, mailchimp

I'm working with a Shopify website that is using MailChimp [chimpified, or mailchimp for shopify] and I'm building a page where a customer can register their product. My goal is to send the user an email with a discount code upon successful registration.

Shopify offers pre-built email templates for things like 'new order notification' and 'order cancelled', but I'd like to build a custom template and send that upon successful registration.

I am all hooked into the successful AJAX of the registration process, but being new to Shopify I'm researching the best way to go about implementing this feature.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about being hooked into the ajax?  Post your code too please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is an email template named 'Customer Account Welcome' . Why dont you use that? You can add your discount code in this template.

Comment: My client is already using the standard Notification templates; in this case, to actually send an email to customers when they open a new account. The product registration in our case is a different step from account registration; doesn't come as a default Shopify feature so that's why we're running into this trouble.

But I like your thinking; maybe I can convince them to let me use one of the unused templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vauchar](http://tr.vauchar.link/2AYALFY) do provide the ability to insert discount codes in any emails for shopify stores. The coupon codes are generated on the fly. For more details you can visit: [Vauchar](http://tr.vauchar.link/2AYALFY)